# Javascript/html align text in middle and add sub-heading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML/javascript code where I have a heading on the page. What I am trying to do is align this heading in the middle(left and right alignment) and then add a sub-heading below it which is also aligned in middle:

```
#BotChatGoesHere {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        height: 600px;
        position: relative;
        width: 460px;
      }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Title1</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--<style>
      .example {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
        width: 300px;
      }

      .example > h2 {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      }
 </style>-->

  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="example">


    </section>

    <div id="BotChatGoesHere"></div>
    <div class ="wc-header">
            <span><b>Welcome!</b></span>
        </div>  
        <div class="wc-message-from wc-message-from-bot">
        <span>How Can I help you</span>
        </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

In the above what I am trying to do is have `Welcome!` be aligned in the middle(left and right alignment) and then just below it has `How Can I help you?` also show up in another band as a sub-heading and aligned in middle. Bot the heading and sub-heading are in separate colored bands.

How can I do this as I don't know HTML or Javascript and looks my try above is not working?

**UPDATE:**

Below is how it looks like currently.As you can see from the pic neither does it aligns to middle(left and right equal) but `How can I help you` gets superimposed. What I want is `Welcome`! to be in one blue band but aligned to middle and then another similar band for `how can I help you?`
[image]

Comment: `class=".wc-message-from wc-message-from-bot"` remove `.`.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I removed it but no change...`Welcome!` and `How can I help you?` still come aligned to left

Comment: Just because you haven't aligned them center/middle, provide proper code.

Comment: You want to center this text in a frame or below it ?

Comment: @norbidrak I have edited my code and have also provided a sample pic about how it look like currently. As you can see from the pic neither does it aligns to middle(left and right equal) but `How can I help you gets superimposed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you were exaclty trying to achieve. I added class ".help-container" to position "How can I help you". You can add different styling- colors, font sizes etc. there, if you want.

```css
#BotChatGoesHere {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        position: relative;
}

.help-container{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 39px;
        margin: 0 !important;
        background-color: #9dfb9d; 
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Title1</title>

<link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--<style>
          .example {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 20px;
            width: 300px;
          }

          .example > h2 {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
          }
     </style>-->

</head>

<body>
<section class="example"></section>

<div id="BotChatGoesHere">
    <div class="wc-header">
        <span><b>Welcome!</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="wc-message-from wc-message-from-bot help-container">
        <span>How Can I help you</span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can I have `How can I help you` also in a colored banner like `Welcome` is? Like a green banner?

Comment: When I save this code as a html file and open in chrome I see a different output. `Welcome` is towards the left and so is `How can I help you`

Comment: @user2916886 Code is the same for Chrome as for any other browser, nothing browser dependent here, "#BotChatGoesHere" and ".help-container" need to be add to .css file. Are you adding it ?

Comment: Yes I added the `BotChatGoesHere` and `.help-container` to my css. After clearing my browser cookies i am able to  see them coming in middle but it is creating a small frame within the whole window and not filling the whole browser window

Comment: @user2916886 You had those values set in you div. You need to be more specific when you ask questions. I altered code, removed frame, and changed color,  and you can change to different in ".help-container".